# How to add 1 milion items in Realm correctly?

Tags: android, realm

I want to choose between native `SQLiteDatabase` and `Realm` to deal with a big amount of data.

For benchmark I add to storage 1 milion of Product entities:

**{id:integer,sku:string,name:string,data_creating:string}**

Using `SQLiteDatabase` it takes near 1 minute 34 seconds on my device.

Using `Realm` it takes more them 10 minutes.

My code is:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
realm.beginTransaction();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000000;i++){
    Product product = realm.createObject(Product.class);
    product.setId(i+1);
    product.setName("Product_"+i);
    product.setSku("SKU__"+i);
    product.setDateCreated(new Date());
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```

How can I improve my code for better time performance?

Comment: `1:34 min` ? 1 hour and 34 minutes?

Comment: @greenapps 1 min 34 sec

Comment: Your issue was most likely the creation of 1000000 objects with `createObject`, because it makes the GC go haywire.

Comment: How much RAM does this thing eat anyway :D It works on Heap for each Product i believe

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov yeap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to be aware that SQLite and Realm are two very different things. Realm is an object store and you are creating a lot of objects in the code shown above. Depending on your model class and the number of rows/objects, you will often see that Realm is a bit slower on inserts. To do a fair comparison, you could compare Realm with one of the many excellent ORMs out there.

Said that, Realm offers a low-level interface (io.realm.internal). I wouldn't recommend you to use it as it is currently undocumented. Your example would look like this:

```
long numberOfObjects = 1000000;
SharedGroup sharedGroup = new SharedGroup("default.realm");            
WriteTransaction writeTransaction = sharedGroup.beginWrite();
Table table = writeTransaction.getTable("class_Product");
table.addEmptyRows(numberOfObjects);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
    table.setLong(0, i, i);              // id
    table.setString(1, i, "Product_"+i); // name
    table.setString(2, i, "SKU__"+i);    // sku
    table.SetDate(3, i, new Date());     // date
}
writeTransaction.commit();
sharedGroup.close();
```

You can now compare two table/row oriented data stores, and you will probably find that Realm is a bit faster than SQLite.

At Realm, we have a few ideas on how to get our object interface to run faster, and we hope to be able to implement them in the near future.

Comment: I have added an issue to give better performance - and not use an undocumented API: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/987

Comment: wow, faster in 3 times. but need some changes to code above to work.

Comment: Refer to the new answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/38891222/2413303

Answer (score 12):

The original question spawned a discussion within Realm, and we ended up adding a faster method to [insert](https://realm.io/docs/java/1.1.1/api/io/realm/Realm.html#insert-io.realm.RealmModel-) objects. The code for creating and inserting 1 mio objects can now be written as:

```
final Product product = new Product();
final Date date = new Date();
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000000; i++){
                product.setId(i+1);
                product.setName("Product_"+i);
                product.setSku("SKU__"+i);
                product.setDateCreated(date);
                realm.insert(product);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what would be the better approach inserting items in a loop just like in this answer or map all the objects and insert them via just one inserOrUpdate()?